# Adding variable numbers of 0's

Tags: excel, replace, excel-formula, substitution

I have a set of locations with the following naming convention:

- KP 0.18 CP 02
- KP 100.33 CP 06
- KP 72.93 CP 09

I want to change all of the KP values so that there are 3 digits before the decimal place, e.g.:

- KP 000.18 CP 02
- KP 100.33 CP 06
- KP 072.93 CP 09

Can anyone think of a way to do this that doesn't involve 10 nested substitute functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Your strings are in `A1:A3`, enter this in `B1` and copy down:

```
=LEFT(A1,3) & REPT("0",7 - FIND(".",A1)) & RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)- 3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1))&TEXT(VALUE(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1),LEN(A1)))," 000.0# ")&MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*2,LEN(A1))&MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)*3,LEN(A1)))
```

[image]